# Caching downloaded images to disk

Tags: ios, disk

I have started writing an image library to download images from the web. Once, I download an image I set it up in an images dictionary (I make sure that the number of images in this dictionary doesn't exceed a certain threshold number, to avoid over memory usage, so I remove images when required). After that, I write that image to  a file using the `writeToFile` method of `NSData`. 
When, an image is requested for, I first check if it exists in the dictionary, if it doesn't, if the file exists at the path using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: uniquePath]`. If its not there, I download the image. All this takes place in an async queue which is set to high priority global queue. But, the entire process still seems a little laggy. Is it ok to use disk reading and writing methods asynchronously in the global queue? Also, is caching to disk recommended in a situation like this? Can it speed up things, if I commit file writes only when I dump images from the dictionary, in low memory conditions?

Comment: how you are downloading images as data from url? By using async url connection or something else?

Comment: You might be interested in this library -> https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Comment: i am using [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]]]. But this takes place asynchronously in the global queue.

Comment: It is a synchronous call so you are experiencing laggy. Make asynchronous call. And use URLCaching for NSUrlRequest.

Comment: so you mean....a synchronous call wrapped within an async block, will still be synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

caching is made easy in [SDWebImage Framework](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage).It by default supports caching.

Comment: yes...I know about SDWebImage, I have never used it yet, I have only used EGOImageView to this end, and it supports caching. But, I am writing my own library, just for the learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to cache stuff is to use Apple's own NSURLCache. Just read this link: http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Basically you need to add this to you `applicationDidFinishLaunching...`

```
let URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 4 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(URLCache)
```